# Set GIF on Background of button

Tags: android, android-animation, gif

is it possible to apply GIF on background of button.I have tried by the following code by taking the reference from [this](http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.in/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html). And my code is below.

```
   public class GIFView extends View {
    Movie movie, movie1;
    InputStream is = null, is1 = null;
    long moviestart;

    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.cloudinary_animation);// avoid error ( “Expected resource of type raw”)by +
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        System.out.println("now=" + now);
        if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
            moviestart = now;

        }
        System.out.println("\tmoviestart=" + moviestart);
        int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        System.out.println("time=" + relTime + "\treltime=" + movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas, this.getWidth() / 2 - 20, this.getHeight() / 2 - 40);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Now I want to apply this animation on the background of button.

Comment: Libraries exist to do this. For example https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have implemented this in my application a day ago.Although this tutorial is >about ImageView you can easily convert the code to your **advantage.**

First of all, it depends on your desire.

> ### 1: Repeatedly continue to play the Gif (It is easy)
>
> ### 2: Play only once similar to Facebook app "Like" button (Some work is required)

---

**Include this library to your gradle.build**

**compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'**

---

```
GifImageView gifImageView;

GifDrawable gifDrawable;
```

---

***Define this variable:***

```
gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.splashGif);
```

```js
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashGif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFDFF"
        />
```

---

**To play the GIF**

```
 public void playGif() {


        try {
            gifDrawable = new GifDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.SplashGifId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        gifDrawable.setLoopCount(1);

        gifDrawable.addAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCompleted(int loopNumber) {

                gifImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.SplashLastFrame));

            }
        });

        gifImageView.setImageDrawable(gifDrawable);



}
```

---

> ***This method will play the gif R.drawable.SplashGifId  after finishing process of GIF you will set the last frame (R.drawable.SplashLastFrame) of GIF to your button or ImageView.***

**To split your gif and get the last frame of your gif, you can use this online tool:**

https://ezgif.com/split

---

Use this resources and inform me... Cheers!