# How to put gif in Button's background? Android

Tags: java, android, button, gif

I would like to know how to put a gif in a Button's background on Android.
I already found out how to put a gif in an image view but I can't find any answer for my problem.

Comment: [As this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843628/8867002), gif is not supported .

Comment: Try this reference for the better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547226/set-gif-on-background-of-button

Comment: If you know how to put gif to the `ImageView`, so why you can not use it as a button?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons do not support gifs as a background resource.
Why does it has to be a button?
Just use an Image-View and react to an onClick event.